# How to handle completion of system UIAlertController in iOS?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, uialertcontroller

So I know how to create a `UIAlertController` and set its completion handler. But is there a way to control what happens when a system deployed alert is displayed?

My situation is that when the user clicks the restore purchases button in my app, I start a `UIActivityIndicatorView`. If the user signs in and the purchases are restored, I can call code to make the activity wheel stop spinning in my Purchase Observer, but if cancel is clicked I don't have a way to stop the wheel and it continues to spin.

Anyone know of a solution?

Comment: Have you tried `paymentQueue:restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:` delegate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
  restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error`

Ref: https://gregheo.com/blog/iap-restore/

Comment: Thanks, Pradeep K. I didn't know about this method, but I just applied it and it works great.